# Does monitor mode need its own drivers?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-driver

I have seen some wifi cards like the CYW43455 on the Raspberry pi 3b+ which supports monitor mode, just not out of the box. To enable monitor mode, you would need nexmon drivers from here:

[Nexmon Github](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon)

Does this mean that even if a wifi chip supports monitor mode, it does not really mean that you will be able to go into monitor mode? For example I have an Xperia Z5 Compact phone, which I have rooted and installed lineage os, it has the BCM43455 wifi card. When I try to enable monitor mode on it, it says monitor mode not supported. I can see under the nexmon list, that BCM43455 is listed as a device that supports monitor mode with nexmon drivers.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you can not directly control hardware from user-mode application. User application sends requests to driver and driver talks to hardware. If driver knows nothing about monitor mode (or it was simple skipped in driver) then it will say that monitor mode is not supported. So yes, you should have driver that knowns about monitor mode and provides some API for user-mode applications to turn this monitor mode and, of course, to bypass all the captured packets to the user app.